# How to filter products on a Product category page with FacetWP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, facetwp

I want to add filters to my WooCommerce product category page. I'm using the FacetWP-plugin. I've added some code to my archive-product.php and I have gotten my filters to show on the page (which is as how I want it) but once I try to filter through the products - nothing is happening.

I've followed the following guide https://elvtn.com/wordpress-plugins/building-product-filter-woocommerce-facetwp/

I've also changed the following to True.
FacetWP - settings - WooCommerce - Support product variations? - True

Facets are also indexed correctly as the categories are showing up on the page but it's not actually filtering anything.

```php
    <div><div class="facetwp-template">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
                 *
                 * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
                 * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
                 * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
            ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php
                        /**
                         * woocommerce_shop_loop hook.
                         *
                         * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
                         */
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
                    ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook.
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
            ?>

        <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_no_products_found hook.
                 *
                 * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
            ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div></div>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_main_content hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
    ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
    ?>
```

I expect that I should be able to filter through my products when I click on the checkbox but this is not happening